# Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'" in Python?

Tags: python, model, lda

I'm trying to generate a Latent Dirichlet Allocation model using 500 different txts. 
One part of my code is as follows:

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
from gensim import corpora, models

bigram = Phrases(docs, min_count=10)
trigram = Phrases(bigram[docs])
for idx in range(len(docs)):
    for token in bigram[docs[idx]]:
        if '_' in token:
            # Token is a bigram, add to document.
            docs[idx].append(token)
    for token in trigram[docs[idx]]:
        if '_' in token:
            # Token is a bigram, add to document.
            docs[idx].append(token)
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
File ".../scriptLDA.py", line 74, in <module>
    docs[idx].append(token)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can someone fix it for me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Python is telling you that docs[idx] is not a list, but a string. Therefore it has no append() method for you to call.

```
>>> fred = "blah blah"
>>> fred.append("Bob")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> elsie = [1,2,3,4]
>>> elsie.append(5)
>>> elsie
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> type(fred)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(elsie)
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

If all you want to do is add your token string to your docs[idx] string then use '+':

```
>>> ginger = fred + "Another string"
>>> ginger
'blah blahAnother string'
```

If it's more complicated then that's a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

append() is used to add elements to the array, not to connect strings.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
you can do:

`a = "string1"
a = a + "string2"`

or:

`a = [1,2,3,4]
a.append(5)`